# Running a .py file on LAMP (CentOS) server - from a PHP developer's perspective

Tags: python, centos

I'm a LAMP developer trying out Python for the first time.. I'm okay with picking up the syntax, but I *can't figure out how to run it on the server!* I've tried the following

- uploading `filename.py` to a regular web/public directory. chmod 777, 711, 733, 773... (variations of execute)
- putting the `filename.py` in cgi-bin, chmod same as above..

Typing up `example.com/filename.py` simply loads a textfile - nothing appears to have been compiled/parsed/etc!

(I believe python is installed, as 
`whereis python` on my server shows  `/usr/bin/python`  among several other directories)

Many words for a simple question - how do you run a python file on a CentOS server?

Comment: This should be on Server Fault.  However, in the mean time, do you know whether your code is a cgi script or uses [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/)?  You may want to post same code.  If it's cgi, you may need to use [AddHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html) cgi-script .py.  If it's CGI, also make sure that you have a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Comment: The code isn't compiled (yet).. just a text file script renamed with extension .py ... I have a shebang as the firstline. How do I check if the script uses mod_python?

Comment: @ina Firstly, the Python interpreter may cache your files, but doesn't compile them. Secondly, http://www.modpython.org/ is an Apache HTTP Server extension. Which instructions have you followed to create your file?

Comment: mod_python is kinda dead these days

Comment: if it's cached... does it mean it'd get compiled eventually? really a bit lost - do i have to compile it offline before deploying it to server? i guess i thought this would be like perl, other than syntax differences, add a shebang, chmod, and presto!

Comment: No no compiling necessary, Python is an interpreted language. When you import another module, the Python interpreter caches the result as a .pyc file itself.

Answer (score 3):

This is a big mental shift from PHP. Python files are not simply interpreted like .php files[1]. The simplest way I have found to get up & running with Python is the [Bottle](http://bottle.paws.de) framework.

I recommend you spend a short while reading http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html. It's very informative.

[1]: Note: there is such a thing as Python Server Pages, but it's not widely used.

Comment: in other words, you can't just load up a python file by typing in its address like http://example.com/filename.py?

Comment: Not really, it's not common practice to mix Python code & HTML like you would in the PHP world. If you are interested in learning how things work, web2py is one of the easiest full-feature Python web programming frameworks to learn.

Comment: well, i plan to use php for formating the data for display, but having php invoke the python file when needed... manually testing if the python file works, I thought the easiest way might be to just load up the URL on browser -- but i guess that won't work without installing Bottle (?) ... how do php files invoke python files anyway?

Comment: Oh, this is a different question than I thought initially. If you want the PHP interpreter to envoke a Python interpreter, I recommend having a search or asking a new question.

Without knowing the detail, there are probably two ways to do this. 1) Ask the operating system to do it, 2) ask the web server to do it.

1) would be a matter of getting python to a result to somewhere that PHP could find it (file/stdout)
2) reference the URL of the .py file, and configure the webserver to envoke the Python interpreter

Answer (score 1):

you can use cgi, but that will not have great performance as it starts a new process for each request.

More efficient alternatives are to use fastcgi or wsgi

A third option is to run a mini Python webserver and proxy the requests from apache using rewrite rules

Comment: another n00b question - is miniPython mod_python?

Comment: @ina, by mini I mean something like bottle or webpy as opposed to larger frameworks such as django or zope

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other comments that there may be more efficient ways to run a Python script. Here are some things to try if you'd just like to run a Python script by dropping it into the cgi-bin directory. You'll first want to locate your httpd.conf file. One way to do this is:

```
locate httpd.conf
```

Your httpd.conf file is probably located at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf for CentOS. Edit the file and make sure Python files are recognized, especially if you will use them outside of the ScriptedAliased directories:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
```

Restart your Apache web-server:

```
apachectl restart
```

Create the following test.py file inside the /var/www/cgi-bin directory (default for CentOS):

```
#! /usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""
print "Hello, World!"
```

You'll want to make the file executable with:

```
chmod 775 test.py
```

That should be all that you'll need to do. You can now visit http://{your-domain}/cgi-bin/test.py and the resulting "Hello, World!" should appear.